# Homogenous and non-Homogenous equations

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the question, that if $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix, with $m\le n$. Then if $Ax=0$ has exactly one solution, then $Ax=b$ has exactly one solution for any $b$. Is this statement true?

Answer (score 0):

If $Ax=0$ has exactly one solution, then $A$ is injective, but it must not necessarily be surjective (indeed it is if, and only if $n=m$), so $Ax=b$ can have either one or zero solutions.

An example for the case with zero solutions is
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & 0\\0 & 1\\0 & 0\end{array}\right)x = \left(\begin{array}{c}1\\1\\1\end{array}\right)$$

Comment: So it is only true when m=n?

Comment: @user105969 Yes.

Comment: The question indicates, though, that either m => n

Comment: or m =< n is true

Comment: @user105969 If $m\le n$, then it is impossible that $Ax=b$ has only one solution.